# Python's Regex findall Does not return All matches of Unicode Text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

I have a unicode text that contains a list of journals with some details about each. I would like retrieve the name of the journals only.

My text is very large and looks like this:

> 6) 6. ACROSS LANGUAGES AND CULTURES Semiannual ISSN: 1585-1923
>   AKADEMIAI KIADO ZRT, BUDAFOKI UT 187-189-A-3, BUDAPEST, HUNGARY,
>   H-1117 Social Sciences Citation Index Arts & Humanities Citation Index
>   7) 7. ACTA ANALYTICA-INTERNATIONAL PERIODICAL FOR PHILOSOPHY IN THE
>   ANALYTICAL TR ADITION Quarterly ISSN: 0353-5150 SPRINGER, 233 SPRING
>   ST, NEW YORK, USA, NY, 10013 Arts & Humanities Citation Index 8) 8.
>   ACTA ARCHAEOLOGICA Annual ISSN: 0065-101X WILEY, 111 RIVER ST,
>   HOBOKEN, USA, NJ, 07030-5774 Arts & Humanities Citation Index 9) 9.
>   ACTA BOREALIA Semiannual ISSN: 0800-3831 ROUTLEDGE JOURNALS, TAYLOR &
>   FRANCIS LTD, 2-4 PARK SQUARE, MILTON PARK, ABINGDON, ENGLAND, OXON,
>   OX14 4RN Arts & Humanities Citation Index 10) 10. ACTA CLASSICA Annual
>   ISSN: 0065-1141 UNIV FREE STATE, DEPT ENG CLASSICAL LANG, PO BOX 339,
>   BLOEMFONTEIN, SOUTH AFRICA, 9300 Arts & Humanities Citation Index 11)
>   11. ACTA HISTORICA TALLINNENSIA Annual ISSN: 1406-2925 ESTONIAN ACADEMY PUBLISHERS, 6 KOHTU, TALLINN, ESTONIA, 10130 Arts & Humanities
>   Citation Index 12) 12. ACTA HISTRIAE Tri-annual ISSN: 1318-0185
>   4￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼ تاریخ انتشار: 89/2/62 پژوهشگاه و شبکه آزمایشگاهی 98/3 :Code
>   UNIV PRIMORSKA, SCI RES CENTRE KOPER, GARIBALDIJEVA 1, KOPER,
>   SLOVENIA, CAPODISTRIA, SI-6000 Social Sciences Citation Index Arts &
>   Humanities Citation Index 13) 13. ACTA KOREANA Semiannual ISSN:
>   1520-7412 ACADEMIA KOREANA KEIMYUNG UNIV, 1095 DALGUBEOLDAERO,
>   DALSEO-GU, DAEGU, SOUTH KOREA, 704-701 Arts & Humanities Citation
>   Index Current Contents - Arts & Humanities 14) 14. ACTA LINGUISTICA
>   HUNGARICA Quarterly ISSN: 1216-8076 AKADEMIAI KIADO ZRT, BUDAFOKI UT
>   187-189-A-3, BUDAPEST, HUNGARY, H-1117 Social Sciences Citation Index
>   Arts & Humanities Citation Index 15)15. ACTA LITERARIA Semiannual
>   ISSN: 0717-6848 UNIV CONCEPCION, FAC HUMANIDADES ARTE, CASILLA 160-C,
>   CORREO 3, CONCEPCION, CHILE, 00000 Arts & Humanities Citation Index
>   16) 16. ACTA MUSICOLOGICA Semiannual ISSN: 0001-6241 INT MUSICOLOGICAL
>   SOC, BOX 561, BASEL, SWITZERLAND, CH-4001 Arts & Humanities Citation
>   Index Current Contents - Arts & Humanities 17) 17. ACTA ORIENTALIA
>   ACADEMIAE SCIENTIARUM HUNGARICAE Quarterly ISSN: 1588-2667 AKADEMIAI
>   KIADO ZRT, BUDAFOKI UT 187-189-A-3, BUDAPEST, HUNGARY, H-1117 Arts &
>   Humanities Citation Index 5￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼ تاریخ انتشار: 89/2/62 پژوهشگاه و
>   شبکه آزمایشگاهی 98/3 :Code Current Contents - Arts & Humanities 18)
>   18. ACTA PHILOSOPHICA Semiannual ISSN: 1121-2179 FABRIZIO SERRA EDITORE, PO BOX NO,1, SUCC NO. 8, PISA, ITALY, I-56123 Arts &
>   Humanities Citation Index Current Contents - Arts & Humanities

It want the match return

> ACROSS LANGUAGES AND CULTURES Semiannual
>
> ACTA ANALYTICA-INTERNATIONAL PERIODICAL FOR PHILOSOPHY IN THE
>   ANALYTICAL TR ADITION Quarterly
>
> ACTA ARCHAEOLOGICA Annual
>
> etc.

I have already tried (https://regex101.com/r/eyafNd/1) and on reg101 website, it seems it works.

```
regex = r"^(\d+\)\s*\d+\.\s+)(.*?) ISSN"
l = re.findall(regex,txt,re.IGNORECASE)
print(len(l))
print(l)
```

What it return is list with only 1 result as follows

```
[('6) 6. ', 'ACROSS LANGUAGES AND CULTURES Semiannual')]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

CS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe take a look at this regex:

```
(?<=\d\.\s).+?(?=\sISSN)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyafNd/2)

```
regex = r"(?<=\d\.\s).+?(?=\sISSN)"
l = re.findall(regex, txt, re.I)
print(len(l))
print(l)
```

This says to start matching following a *number+dot+whitespace* and up to the characters *whitespace+ISSN*. I can then confirm that when I write your text, I receive the following output list with your code:

```
['ACROSS LANGUAGES AND CULTURES Semiannual', 'ACTA ANALYTICA-INTERNATIONAL PERIODICAL FOR PHILOSOPHY IN THE ANALYTICAL TR ADITION Quarterly', 'ACTA ARCHAEOLOGICA Annual'...]
```